# Get current call object after Verto FreeSwitch recovering call

Tags: jquery, freeswitch, mod-verto

How can I get back the currentCall object on a Verto FreeSwitch?
I am using [this guide from the Verto Documentation](http://evoluxbr.github.io/verto-docs/tut/recovering-a-call.html).
When I want to hangup after a tab refresh, I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'hangup' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.hangupCall

and when i try to print it, it says "undefined".
What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research it seems that i didn't read well the doc.
My bad.

This line on the onDialog State function make it.

```
if (!currentCall) {
     currentCall = dialog;
}
```